# Iterating matching elements over two arrays in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I have two lists containing objects of similar type and am looking to operate on the intersecting objects.

Is there a way to simplify this kind of loop using CoffeeScript?

```
for a in aList
    for b in bList
        if a.id == b.id
            doSomething a
```

This is the best I can come up with but it's still a bit messy:

```
doSomething a for a in aList when a.id in (b.id for b in bList)
```

Any golfing or compilation optimization is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I thought 2 patterns for your situation. Please think of this as one of several answers.

### Pattern 1

The simple way which was written at your script is below.

```
for a in aList
    for b in bList
        if a.id == b.id
            doSomething a
```

When this is converted as a comprehension script, that is below.

```
doSomething b for b in bList when b.id is a.id for a in aList
```

When both scripts are compiled, the result is the same as follows.

```
for (i = 0, len = aList.length; i < len; i++) {
  a = aList[i];
  for (j = 0, len1 = bList.length; j < len1; j++) {
    b = bList[j];
    if (a.id === b.id) {
      doSomething(a);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note :

- This way is faster than your `doSomething a for a in aList when a.id in (b.id for b in bList)`.

### Pattern 2

```
aList.map (a) -> bList.filter (b) -> a.id is b.id && doSomething a
```

When this script is compiled, the result is as follows.

```
aList.map(function(a) {
  return bList.filter(function(b) {
    return a.id === b.id && doSomething(a);
  });
});
```

#### Note :

- This way is slower than your `doSomething a for a in aList when a.id in (b.id for b in bList)`.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: I like the `map` and `filter` solution. That's a nice approach. Shame about performance. Thanks!

Comment: @Milk Welcome. I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.